# HDMI output not working after install

Tags: nvidia, 13.10, hdmi

I've installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my HP Envy 17. I have a Intel graphic chip and a NVIDIA chip. GeForce GT 740M). But after installing it the HDMI monitor isn't detected anymore.

Installing the corresponding NVIDIA drivers (I tried nvidia-319, nvidia-updates-319 or nvidia-current) lead to low resolution and compiz being unable to start.

But while installing I get the HDMI monitor as second screen. How could I enable that again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out bumblebee destroyed everything. It added ubuntu-319 to the blacklist. I wasn't able to find every place where it touched config files so I wiped the system and did a clean reinstall.

After that the HDMI port worked again. I let it be at that and didn't even installed the NVIDIA drivers.

Not a very satisfying solution, but a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could benifit from installing Bumblebee. I've read that they have uber control over the Intel/Nvidia hybrid graphic cards, so you might get something out of that.

Have a look here: [Bumblebee Project](http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html)

Comment: Did you actuall try that? I have troubles to get multiple monitors to run. See documentation here: https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Multi-monitor-setup

Comment: It even states that deinstalling bumblebee may be a good solution too

Comment: As I don't have an Intel/Nvidia hybrid I haven't tried it out no. I said that you might get something out of it.

Comment: Don't meant to sound harsh. But I'm courrious why it works for the system booted before install and what there's different to the installed system.

Comment: My ATI/ATI hybrid laptop would disable the Descrete card (equalant of your nvidia one) when i installed proprietary drivers, but would have both cards active if using the open source drivers (which in turn would make it very hot with 2 cards running at the same time). Resulting in my HDMI output only working on Open Source Drivers. Yours might be different as you use nvidia for yours.